# How does a dirty EditorPart prohibit Eclipse from renaming its resource?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Say I have defined my own `TextEditorX extends TextEditor`. In the typical Eclipse-RCP scenario (standard plugins, workbench with Project Explorer/ Navigator) the behaviour when  someone tries to rename (via Project Explorer or Navigator) a file that some editor has opened is:

- If the editor is not `dirty`, the renaming is allowed. Afterwards `editor.setInput()` will be called, with the new filename as argument.
- If it's `dirty`, an error is thrown (*"Rename resource" : "A fatal error occurred while performing the refactoring" "Found problems: doc.txt is unsaved"*).

My questions:

- At which level is this behaviour defined? I guess that the package `org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource` is involved... But, suppose for example that I want to disallow the rename even when the editor is not dirty: could this behaviour be determined by some method in the editor (or the document provider), or should I code/extend some `RenameParticipant` ?
- How does the renamer knows that the resource `doc.txt` is opened by that editor instance? Does it just check all opened editors and ask each one for its `editorInput`, or are `documentProviders` involved? Specifically, suppose I have a particular editor that, besides the "main" file, depends on other resources (a multi-file input), and it want the renamer to ask him before renaming any of his inputs. How would you approach this scenario?

Comment: Haven't got the source code here, so it's hard to look at what classes are involved where, but for your first question, have you considered simply overriding `isDirty()` to return `true` in your editor? You could still use `super.isDirty()` if you need to find out whether it's actually changed...

Comment: Wouldn't a side effect of this be that the little "this thing is dirty" asterisk on the editor part's tab would never go away?  This might make users scratch their heads.

Answer (score 0):

There's no theoretical reason for Eclipse to prevent a rename of a modified file. For one, the editor could register a ResourceChangeListener with the workspace, and simply update its IEditorInput in response to a MOVE notification. Not sure if that is a good answer but maybe a good approach to go.